# MySQLiで複数テーブルの、「同じ名称の項目」で比較し並べ替える

Tags: php, mysql

会員ごとにテーブルを作っています

テーブル：田中
身長|体重|体脂肪
テーブル：山田
身長|体重|体脂肪
・
・
・
これを体重が重い順に並び替える時クエリはどうすればいいのでしょうか。

複数テーブルを操るSQLはないとの書き込みもありますがPHP側で操作比較するしか無いのでしょうか

Comment: 会員ごとにテーブルを作っている、という事は 1 つのテーブルに 1 レコードのみ登録されているという状態なのでしょうか…？ テーブルを 1 つにして、そこに会員のデータを集約するわけにはいかないのでしょうか？

Comment: metropolisさんに同意します。それにたとえ履歴をもつとしても、1つにまとめたいところです。例えば、身長・体重・体脂肪を追加するテーブルと、ユーザの情報をまとめるテーブルを作って関係を持たせ、クエリで抽出したほうがいいような気がします。質問内容だとテーブルが際限ないので、`information_schema`を見に行かないといけないような気がしますし、結合するにしてもテーブル数が予測できないので、かなりの負荷をサーバに強いることになるし、実行時間が遅くて使い物にならないと思います。